# express 4.x json empty object

Tags: javascript, json, express

I'm trying to return an object as json with express. But here is what I don't understand:

```
class Greeting {
  Greeting(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  get name() {
    return name;
  }
}

app.get('/json/:name', function (req, res) {
  greeting = new Greeting(req.params.name)
  greeting.something = req.params.name
  res.json(greeting)
})
```

http://localhost:3001/json/someparam

Returns:

```
{
"something": "someparam"
}
```

Why does it not return the name set via constructor as well?

Comment: Are you sure this works?

Comment: You mean if I get the output I posted? Yes I'm sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
get name() { return name; }
```

`name` is not defined here so accessing

```
greeting.name
```

will throw a syntax error. And even if you would fix that, getters are not part of an object, and will not get serialized, therefore it behaves as expected. If you would completely remove this unnecessary getter it will work as you think it should. And another obvious thing i missed is that the constructor in javascript is called `constructor`.

Comment: I removed `get name() { return name; }` but still get the same result. I would expect that it will return `{ "something": "someparam", "name": "someparam"}`.

Comment: @alex f oh rename `Greeting(name)` to `constructor(name)`, i coded a lot in java the last time so I completely missed that

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I also a Java developer, that why I missed it.